# Git add changes after compiled .Net solution - GIT ignore

Tags: git, gitignore

i using GIT for my project, but i've a problem.

When I have no pending changes and I make a compilation of the project from visual studio, and then i execute "git status command" it generates all these changes for me

[image]

in my ignore file, i added the extensions, but git doesn't consider them.

[image]

Why does this happen and how can I solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that these files are already being tracked by git.  Run the following:

`git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -m "Fixed .gitignore"`